# How to test the series for convergence involving repeating sequences in the denominator and numerator?

Tags: calculus

I have to test the following factorial for convergence:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{7\cdot15\cdot23\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(8n-1)}{8\cdot17\cdot26\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(9n-1)}$$

What I have attempted to do is use the ratio test as such:

$$\lim_{n\to 0}\lvert (\frac{8n+7}{9n+8})(\frac{9n-1}{8n-1})\rvert = 1$$

This means that the use of this test is inconclusive. I also feel as though the steps I made in this is incorrect. Something about my work does not seem right, I cannot piece it together.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$a_n =\frac {\prod_{i=1}^n(8i-1) } {\prod_{i=1}^n(9i-1) }=\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)}\,\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{7}{8}\right)}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{8}{9}\right)}$$
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{8 n+7}{9 n+8} \quad \to \frac{8}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your ratio is wrong.  Note that $9n-1$ and $8n-1$ are factors in $a_n$ as well as $a_{n+1}$, so they should cancel out when you take $a_{n+1}/a_n$.